# python spider closed without scraping any URL

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm writing a spider with URLs composed from a CSV file. By executing it, no items are scraped.
here is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
import csv    
import requests
from parsel import Selector
from scrapy.selector import Selector 
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class Tayara(scrapy.Spider):
name="tayarabureau"    
compteur=1
def parse(self, response):        
    with open('TayaraBureaux.csv',encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')            
        for row in csv_reader:            
            title = row[2].replace(' ', '-')  
            adurl = 'https://www.tayara.tn/listings/bureaux-et-plateaux-140/'+row[1]+'/'+title        
            yield scrapy.Request(adurl, self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
    #item={}
    source = 'Tayara'        
    reference = response.url.split('//')[1].split('/')[3]
    titre = response.xpath('//h1[@data-name="adview_title"]/text()').extract()   
    gouvernorat = response.xpath('//p[@data-name="adview_location"]/text()').extract()[0].split(', ')[0]
    delegation = response.xpath('//p[@data-name="adview_location"]/text()').extract()[0].split(', ')[1]        
    yield{'Source':source, 'Reference':reference, 'Titre':titre, 'Gouvernorat':gouvernorat, 'Delegation':delegation}
```

Here is the message I received after the spider is closed without any item scraped:

```
> 2019-01-29 17:34:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
> 2019-01-29 17:34:14 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages
> (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2019-01-29 17:34:14
> [tayarabureau] INFO: Spider opened: tayarabureau 2019-01-29 17:34:14
> [tayarabureau] INFO: Spider opened: tayarabureau 2019-01-29 17:34:14
> [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
> 127.0.0.1:6023 2019-01-29 17:34:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished) 
> 2019-01-29 17:34:14 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO:
> Dumping Scrapy stats: {'finish_reason': 'finished',  'finish_time':
> datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 16, 34, 14, 403625), 
> 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,  'log_count/INFO': 9,  'start_time':
> datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 16, 34, 14, 359624)} 2019-01-29
> 17:34:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Could it be that the site is rendered client side, therefore there is nothing for Scrapy to find? Best way to find out is to interact with the site via Scrapy Shell. More details in https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/05/18/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-may-2016-edition

Comment: it works perfectly in scrapy shell

Answer (score 0):

Actually you providing an empty url in parsing which you need to provide before.
`scrapy.spider` contain param `start_urls` which is in default empty. What you need to do is append the url before parsing.

check out this code.

```
import scrapy
import csv    
import requests
from parsel import Selector
from scrapy.selector import Selector 
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class Tayara(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "tayarabureau"
    compteur = 1
    start_urls = []
    with open('TayaraBureaux.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        for row in csv_reader:
            title = row[2].replace(' ', '-')
            adurl = 'https://www.tayara.tn/listings/bureaux-et-plateaux-140/'+row[1]+'/'+title
            start_urls.append(adurl)

    def parse(self, response):
        #item={}
        source = 'Tayara'
        reference = response.url.split('//')[1].split('/')[3]
        titre = response.xpath('//h1[@data-name="adview_title"]/text()').extract()
        gouvernorat = response.xpath('//p[@data-name="adview_location"]/text()').extract()[0].split(', ')[0]
        delegation = response.xpath('//p[@data-name="adview_location"]/text()').extract()[0].split(', ')[1]
        yield({'Source':source, 'Reference':reference, 'Titre':titre,
               'Gouvernorat':gouvernorat, 'Delegation':delegation})
```

Here the output I get:

```
2019-02-07 11:28:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-02-07 11:28:23 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-02-07 11:28:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) 
<GET https://www.tayara.tn/listings/bureaux-et-plateaux-140/b54871b9-cad3 4113-97ce-a2eac095146f/chambre-d'enfant> (referer: None)
{'Source': 'Tayara', 'Reference': 'b54871b9-cad3-4113-97ce-a2eac095146f', 
'Titre': ["chambre d'enfant"], 'Gouvernorat': 'Nabeul', 'Delegation': 'El Haouaria'}
2019-02-07 11:28:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-02-07 11:28:24 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 298,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 33258,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 2, 28, 24, 680904),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 2, 28, 23, 33853)}
2019-02-07 11:28:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

---

By the way, if you crawling multiple site and needed to create customize `url` before parsing, use [scrapy-redis](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-redis) where you can feed the url to spiders through redis.

If you need some additional parameter along with url, you can go with [scrapy-redis-json-support](https://github.com/PS3132/scrapy-redis-json-support)